# Can't save dynamic crosstab in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, crosstab

I have been working with Access to do some simple queries but as data and query complexity increase I had to start working with MSSQL.
I've been learning MSSQL by trial and error and by consulting stackoverflow but I couldn't figure out a way to overcome my latest wall.

I need to build a crosstab dynamically but I have been unable to save data in a table.

For sake of brevity I've shorten the query below:

```
1  IF OBJECT_ID('#TEMPF','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMPF
2  IF OBJECT_ID('#TEMPUF','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMPUF
3  IF OBJECT_ID('#TEMPVAR','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMPVAR
4 
5  SELECT * INTO #TEMPF FROM ...
6  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) AS ID, * INTO #TEMPUF FROM ...
7
8  DECLARE @TCMAX ...
9  DECLARE @INCREMENT MONEY ...
10
11 SELECT * INTO #TEMPVAR FROM #TEMPUF CROSS APPLY ...
12
13 DECLARE @TCUB ...
14 DECLARE @TCLB ...
15 DECLARE @LABEL NVARCHAR(...)
16 DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX)
17 DECLARE @NUM ...
18
19 WHILE (@TCLB <= @TCMAX) BEGIN
20   SET @LABEL = ...
21   SET @CMD = N'DECLARE @INCREMENT MONEY = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(...),@INCREMENT,1) + N' 
22   ALTER TABLE #TEMPUF
23   ADD ' + @LABEL + N' FLOAT
24   INSERT INTO #TEMPUF (' + @LABEL + N')
25   SELECT ' + @LABEL + N'
26   FROM #TEMPVAR
27   CROSS APPLY
28   (SELECT ... AS ' + @LABEL + N' FROM #TEMPF
29   WHERE ...) AS ALIAS'
30   EXEC(@CMD)
31   SET @TCUB += ...
32   SET @TCLB += ...
33   SET @NUM += ...
34 END
35
36 SELECT * FROM #TEMPUF
37
38 DROP TABLE #TEMPF
39 DROP TABLE #TEMPUF
40 DROP TABLE #TEMPVAR
41 GO
```

The above query throw invalid column name error message.
I've try to divide the @cmd [line 21-29] in 2 @cmds being the 1st the alter command [line 22-23] (success) and the 2nd the insert command [line 24-29] (fail).
I've also try to further divide the 2nd @cmd by doing the insert command outside. Although the select command [line 25-29] works well, SQL have throw the same invalid column name error message.

It's clearly a problem in the insert command but by doing a select command of #TEMPUF I've checked the columns are being added. I can't think of a solution.

I appreciate your help!

```
1 DECLARE @INCREMENT MONEY ...
2 INSERT INTO #TEMPUF (BIN1)
3 SELECT BIN1 FROM #TEMPVAR
4 CROSS APPLY
5 (SELECT COALESCE(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT CONT) AS FLOAT)/NULLIF(CAST(#TEMPVAR.DCTC AS FLOAT)
6 , 0.0), 0.0) AS BIN1
7 FROM #TEMPF
8 WHERE ...) AS ALIAS
```

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are doing here. I have a feeling it is not as efficient as it could be when I see a bunch of dynamic sql inside a while loop. Check out this article about dynamic cross tabs. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: Basically, I'm want to do a cross apply between #TEMPVAR with #TEMPF and stored in the last recently created column in #TEMPUF.
The storage is necessary because I need to do more cross applies than data type NVARCHAR(MAX) can hold.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a PRINT of the sql command that is generating the error, and which column name the error says is invalid?   I see that you are creating a temp table in the non-dynamic code, and then trying to reference it in a dynamic query, which I'm pretty sure is not possible, since the temp table isn't global.

Comment: @TabAlleman Temp tables belong to the connection and the dynamic sql runs in the same connection but a different context. I think you are remembering variables that fall out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sweating a lot I found a solution for my problem.

Although it is still ugly I've change from insert command to update command.
I've use ID column, since #TEMPVAR is create from #TEMPUF.
The revised @CMD below.

Thanks anyone for your time and effort!

```
21 SET @CMD = N'DECLARE @INCREMENT MONEY = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(...), @INCREMENT, 0) + N';
22 WITH SHADOW AS (SELECT ID, ' + @LABEL + N' FROM #TEMPVAR
23 CROSS APPLY
24 (SELECT ... AS ' + @LABEL + N'
25 FROM #TEMPF
26 WHERE ...) AS ALIAS)
27 UPDATE #TEMPUF
28 SET ' + @LABEL + N' = SHADOW.' + @LABEL + '
29 FROM SHADOW
30 WHERE #TEMPUF.ID = SHADOW.ID'
31 EXEC(@CMD)
```